# Using <include> in custom compound view results in NullPointerException in onFinishInflate()

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-xml

I'm trying to implement a simple custom dial pad view. It was all working fine until I tried to use `<include>` to include a "template" for my buttons instead of explicitly defining each button in the XML file. Since I'm gonna have 12 near-identical buttons I thought I'd just make my XML a bit neater and shorter by doing this.

The problem is that in `onFinishInflate()` in my custom view, when I call `findViewById(R.id.dialpad_view_btn1)` it returns null. I am of course assigning the id `dialpad_view_btn1` to one of my `<include>`'s. If I simply define the button explicitly instead of including from my "template" it works fine. Is there any workaround for this, or should I just accept that `findViewById()` and `<include>` don't play well together?

**DialPadView.java**

```
public class DialPadView extends android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout {


    public DialPadView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initializeViews(context);
    }

    public DialPadView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initializeViews(context);
    }

    public DialPadView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initializeViews(context);
    }

    private void initializeViews(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialpad_view, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        // This call to findViewById() results in a NullPointerException
        ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.dialpad_view_btn1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // I'm just a dummy
            }
        });
    }

}
```

**dialpad_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.me.myproject.DialPadView"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/dialpad_grid_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    grid:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    grid:columnCount="3"
    grid:rowCount="4">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/dialpad_view_btn1"
        layout="@layout/dialpad_button" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/dialpad_view_btn2"
        layout="@layout/dialpad_button" />


</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

**dialpad_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
        grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
        grid:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:text="Test" />

</merge>
```

Comment: Try removing the `<merge>` tag from `dialpad_button.xml` making the `<Button>` a root of this file.

Comment: use <full.path.to.DialPadView> in your xml, not <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>

Comment: @pskink That's the XML **for** `DialPadView`, not for the layout that's using the custom view.

Comment: i dont get you, where do you create DialPadView then?

Comment: @pskink In the layout for my `Activity` of course, didn't think I needed to include that as well since it's not relevant for the question? You think I should include `AndroidManifest.xml`, `build.gradle`, etc. as well?

Comment: sure not, just xml layout where you use DialPadView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem with ids:

The problem you encountered is caused by mixing `<include>` and `<merge>` tags.
Please notice that `<merge>` serves different purpose and it should not be used in this case, so please use only `<incluce>` and make `<Button>` a root in your dialpad_button.xml file. Then all ids should be assigned properly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    grid:layout_columnWeight="1"
    grid:layout_rowWeight="1"
    grid:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:text="Test" />
```

### Details:

If you are curious about this problem you can check the [parseInclude()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-release/core/java/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#768) method in LayoutInflater source file. You can find there a code handling `<merge>` inflation. You can see that the code for passing layout and id attributes to the child of `<include>` is not invoked for `<merge>` because `<merge>` should be used for different scenarios. there:

```
if (TAG_MERGE.equals(childName)) {
    // Inflate all children.
    rInflate(childParser, parent, childAttrs, false);
} else {
    [...]

    // We try to load the layout params set in the <include /> tag. If
    // they don't exist, we will rely on the layout params set in the
    // included XML file.

    [...]

    // Attempt to override the included layout's android:id with the
    // one set on the <include /> tag itself.
    TypedArray a = mContext.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
        com.android.internal.R.styleable.View, 0, 0);
    int id = a.getResourceId(com.android.internal.R.styleable.View_id, View.NO_ID);
    // While we're at it, let's try to override android:visibility.

    [...]
}
```

### Other problems:

It's not strictly related with your problem with missing ids, but as [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) mentioned you wrongly inflate `<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>` inside your custom `DialPadView` so you will end up with hierarchy like this:

```
<DialPadView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
        <Button/>
        <Button/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
</DialPadView>
```

but `<DialPadView>` is already an instance of `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout`, so basically you end up having `GridLayout` inside of `GridLayout`. Apart from not being optimal it may result in layout looking in a different way than you've imagined it to look and behave.

Comment: This was the answer to my question. However, it turns out the question was wrong. In order to simplify the code I changed from using `ImageButton` instead of `Button`. When using `ImageButton`s with a transparent background, it seems like the buttons don't show up when not using `<merge>` as root. On further investigation, the buttons **do** show up, but they don't scale to the `GridLayout`, and the images don't show up. I'll start a new question since now the problem is no longer `NullPointerException`, now it's a matter of layouts. Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer to focus on the thing that pskink mentioned. Even though it is not a reason for your `NullPointerException` mentioned in this question this is still a wrong thing to do and you should investigate and fix it.

Comment: I tried using `<merge>` as the root of my DialPadView, but that breaks the functionality of the `GridLayout` - all it's children just end up on the same line, not in rows and columns. Should I instead inherit my view class from something other than `GridLayout`, to avoid having two nested GridLayouts? Things actually do work as expected when both the root element and the base class are `GridLayout`...

Comment: Two solutions: 1. If you want to inflate children inside your DialPadView  file you need to use `<merge>` tag instead of `<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>` but then you will loose all your attributes from it (merge cannot pass attribures) so you will need to apply them in activity XML file. 2. Just replace `<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>` with your `DialPadView ` class in XML file and use this as a part of activity. Then DO NOT inflate child views inside your custom class. They will be already inflated there. You can create a new question because char limit here is too small :(

Comment: Couldn't I just extend `LinearLayout` in my DialPadView class and keep `GridLayout` as the XML root?

Comment: Of course you can do it, but you will end up with not optimal hierarchy. Sometimes it's ok to do it that way, but you must be sure that you understand all consequences. If you want to go this way please do not use `LinearLayout`, because you won't use any of it's features. Consider extending `FrameLayout` or even `ViewGroup` directly.